# What is this kitchen tool - a handle, and coil of metal around a metal plate?

Tags: equipment

I'm at a loss for what these things are for - they came in a bag with some other things I bought at a thrift store.

[image: unidentified kitchen tool]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're cocktail strainers, and they do what they sound like! More precisely, you use it to strain the cocktail on the way out of the shaker.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_strainer

Comment: Specifically, this is the variety known as a "Hawthorne strainer" per its inventor, typically used when straining from a mixing tin.  There is also a variety known as a "Julep strainer" used for cocktails stirred in a mixing glass: http://www.worldwidedrinks.com/julep.html

Comment: @logophobe The presence in the page you linked of the word *olive's* repeated several times is highly offensive to mine eyes!!!

Comment: Thank you! Question about etiquette here: should I change the title to somehow include the words "Hawthorne strainer"?

Comment: @ErikE I won't argue with you there - I was looking mostly at the pictures of the strainers.  But now I have to keep the link so that your comment makes sense in context.

Comment: One important thing to know is that these are made to fit a specific size of glass or metal shaker. You can use them on any glass as long as it's rim is the right size.

Comment: @GdD Yes and no.  That's the purpose of the metal coil, to ensure straining across a range of glass sizes.  The purpose of the protruding tabs is to keep the strainer from falling into larger containers.  So there's a lot of variability in that "specific size".